# Как выбрать все item в QTreeWidget, которые отмечены?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

Как выбрать все Item в QTreeWidget у которых статус `Qt::Checked`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я формирую QTreeWidget следующим образом :

```
void VisualInspectionData::TreeWidgetListFiles(QStringList imagePathListCopy, QString DeviceFolder, QString DeviceId) {
   if (DeviceFolder.isEmpty()) { DeviceFolder = "устройство не определено"; }
   FilesTreeWidget->setColumnCount(1);
   QTreeWidgetItem * item;
   QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> items;
   for (int i = 0; i < imagePathListCopy.size(); ++i) {
       item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
       item->setText(0,QFileInfo(imagePathListCopy.at(i)).fileName());
       item->setStatusTip(0,imagePathListCopy.at(i));
       item->setCheckState(0, Qt::Unchecked);
       item->setIcon(0,QIcon(imagePathListCopy.at(i)));
       items.append(item);
   }
   FilesTreeWidget->insertTopLevelItems(0, items);
   connect(FilesTreeWidget,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)),this,SLOT(TreeWidgetItemClick(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
}
```

Comment: Под выбрать понимается именно проставить атрибут `selected`?

Comment: так это не домашний проект ? оО 
я то думал

Comment: @Bearded Beaver Нет не проставить атрибут selected. А выбрать все Item с CheckState(Qt::Checked)

Comment: @vegorov  Да не домашний

Comment: @IvanTriumphov повторяю вопрос. Что значит "выбрать"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаем обход элементов первого столбца дерева и собираем в список, те, у кого стоит флажок:

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> childs;

for (int i = 0; i < TreeWidget->topLevelItemCount(); i++) {
    QTreeWidgetItem * item = TreeWidget->topLevelItem(i);
    if (item->checkState(0) == Qt::Checked) {
        childs.append(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, что-то я затупил и подумал про таблицу. Подправил ответ чтобы он соответствовал решению для дерева